# Linux Extract Matched Text Field from File

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, awk

I have a file which has many lines of the format:

```
bc("STG1/Phone") = {type=bana_pub; cbb=12.354; abb=0.0}`
```

I'm looking to extract `cbb=12.354;`.  Currently, I'm doing the following:

```
cat input_file.txt | grep cbb | awk -F " " '{ print $4 }'`
```

The problem is that my approach is *location* specific i.e. assumes it's always 4th field. How do I extract text of the form `cbb=` knowing after the `=` it could be any length and the semi-colon `;` is optional.  The only guarantee I have is that the term `cbb=12.354;` will be surrounded by whitespace if that helps.  The file in future may be of the format:

```
bc("STG1/Phone") = {type=bana_pub; cbb=12.354; abb=0.0}
bc("STG1/Phone") = {type=bana_pub;  abb=0.0; cbb=12.354}
```

My gut tells me regex is probably the way to go, but I generally try and avoid it if I can as I prefer simple matching tools (which I understand better).

Thanks in anticipation for your help.

Comment: A one-liner is mandatory or a bash script is allowed?

Comment: Preference is one liner but I'm looking to learn - so yes bash scripts are allowed.

Comment: You should add a more complete input file snippet that includes lines where the desired string is at different positions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
grep -Eo 'cbb=[^;}]+'
```

**Let's test it:**

```
$ grep -Eo 'cbb=[^;}]+' <<<'bc("STG1/Phone") = {type=bana_pub; cbb=12.354; abb=0.0}`'
$ cbb=12.354
```

**Explanation:**

When you use `... | grep cbb | ...` you're using basic regex. Advanced regex isn't so complicated.

Option `-E` is for advanced regex, useful for don't escape some metacharacters. `-o` is for print just what grep matches instead the whole line.

The regex `cbb=[^;}]+`would be the same for any other cmd, not just grep.

`cbb=` is a fixed string, no metacharacter there (`c` followed by `b` etc)

`[^;}]+` square brackets delimit a character set in a single position. A caret at the beginning means negated character set. The plus sign means one or more character. This way it will match any character, at least one, until it finds a `;` or `}`

Here's a good link to learn more about regexes:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation of how it works?

Comment: It's certainly does work and it's easy enough for me to remember.

Comment: Thanks, selected because I like it's simplicity and easy enough to remember.

Answer (score 2):

This works and is position-independent:

```
grep cbb input_file.txt | awk -F "cbb=" '{ print $2 }'| awk -F ";" '{print "cbb=" $1}'
```

First it selects only lines containing `cbb`, then uses the string `cbb=` as separator and finally uses `;` as field separator adding the string **cbb=** to the final result.

Comment: Confirmed that this works.  For line 1 I get `cbb=12.354` and for line 2 I get `cbb=12.354}` as your trick in using `;` is not applicable (doesn't have one).  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sed (since sed is called only once, should be faster)

```
sed -n 's/^.*\(cbb=[0-9\.]*\).*$/\1/p' sample.txt
```

Where sample.txt is your input file. Check only for numerical ([0-9.]) to address a possible issue with optional semicolon.

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation of how it works?

Comment: I used sed to substitute a string caught by RE with the group captured by re itself.

RegExp cbb=[0-9\.]*\ within a capture group '( ... )' search for cbb= followed by any number of digit plus '.' and \1 return the first match found.

option -n is needed to have a quiet behavior while p at the end mean print the result 

I choose sed over awk 'cause in awk capture group are not available (gawk not considered)

Note 2: capture group is the regular expression delimited by '(' and ')' it must be escaped

Note 3: Sanity check is not performed (e.g. 123.45.67 will be parsed as a number)

Comment: Thanks, feel free to add it to your answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `grep` is the right tool for the job. However, I thought I'd add:

- **Perl**

  ```
  perl -lane 'print $1 if /(cbb=[^;}]+)/' input_file.txt
  ```
- **AWK**

  ```
  awk 'match($0,/cbb=[^;}]+/,m) {print m[0]}' input_file.txt
  ```
- **Sed**

  ```
  sed -rn 's/.*(cbb=[^;}]+).*/\1/p' input_file.txt
  ```

---

Credits to Paulo for understanding what the OP meant with:

> after the `=` it could be any length and the semi-colon `;` is optional.
>   The only guarantee I have is that the term `cbb=12.354;` will be
>   surrounded by whitespace